# Data can also be imported by specifying columns

Tags: time-series, cnosdb

Data can also be imported by specifying columns

I check the [CnosDB office doc](https://docs.cnosdb.com/zh/latest/manage/import_export.html#%E5%AF%BC%E5%85%A5%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE),Importing data by specifying column names is also successful, but there is no relevant syntax description in the document.

the syntax as follow:

```
COPY INTO [database.]<table_name>
FROM '<path>'
FILE_FORMAT (
    TYPE = {'CSV' | 'NDJSON' | 'PARQUET'} [,DELIMITER = '<character>'] [,WITH_HEADER = true | false]
)
COPY_OPTIONS (
    auto_infer_schema = true | false
)
```

I imported the data as follows：

```
public ❯ COPY INTO inner_csv_v2(time, tag1, tag2, bigint_c, string_c, ubigint_c, boolean_c, double_c) FROM 'query_server/test/resource/data_type/csv/full_data_type.csv' file_format = (type = 'csv');
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 1    |
+------+
Query took 0.008 seconds.
```

How come the actual syntax is different from the description in the documentation?

Comment: Because the documentation isn't very good?

Comment: @NickW I'm wondering if this is because the documentation is incomplete and there is an undisclosed interface.